# What's the word of a Transmission Control Protocol port in the Wireshark captured package?

Tags: wireshark, transport-protocol

What's the meaning of the `dict` there? why the port have the paraphrase? you see the `Destination port 39578 (39578)` do not have.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wireshark provides an immense amount of background information and tries to parse as much as possible out of a frame.

The TCP port 2628 is used for *dictionary service* ([RFC 2229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2229)) which seems to be running on 202.85.215.42. Of course, Wireshark can't really tell which application-layer protocol is used, it just guesses from the port number.